# Trying to run tests on Spring Boot test properties configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I have Spring Boot application that normally runs on Postgres DB, however I'd like to test some features on an embedded H2 DB.
I have tried annotating my test classes with `@TestPropertySource`and I have tried creating test and dev profiles (separate application.properties files) but none of these seem to be working.

This is my application-test.properties

```
server.port=8080

spring.resources.add-mappings=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
```

which is accompanied by my test data.sql script :

```
insert into people(first_name, last_name, id) values('John', 'Johnson', 8);
insert into vehicles(name, make) values ('Mustang', 'Ford');
```

However even though I annotate my test class like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-test.properties"})
```

It still tries to run the app with the regular Postgres DB  and it is using the Postgres DB data.sql rather than the one specified above. If I switch the regular data.sql with the test one I get an error like this :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Are there any other ways to do this? None of the solutions I could find worked for me.

Comment: What does your regular properties look like? Have you tried setting spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect, since thats what its complaining about?

Comment: The dialect for test properties is set as you can see, the main problem for me however is how to get Spring to recognize those test properties (shown above) and then to use them while starting up the context.

Comment: you could try setting @ActiveProfiles("test"), also perhaps the issue is with your file structure? do you have the standard src/test/java and src/test/resources folders?

Comment: Yes sadly I have tried these things before and none of them worked. I do have the src/test/java and src/test/resources folders.

Comment: i see the dialect is set, but perhaps it needs to be set twice, as perhaps setting spring.jpa.database-platform doesnt propogate the dialect to the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect property, its worth a shot if you havent already tried it